# DragDeltaEventArgs HorizontalChange and VerticalChange not right

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I am programmatically raising the MouseLeftButtonDown event on a Thumb to force the keyboard focus and mouse capture of the Thumb so that it's DragDelta event will fire.

The problem is that the DragDeltaEventArgs passed into the DragDelta event are weird negative numbers. This causes me to have to move the mouse considerably before the numbers become positive and the Thumb begins the resize calculation of the object.  By then the cursor is off of the Thumb.  I would like the cursor to stay on the Thumb.

Here is the code for raising the MouseLeftButtonDown event:

```
bottomRight.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, Environment.TickCount, MouseButton.Left) { RoutedEvent = Thumb.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent});
```

Is there anything different that I can do to avoid the weird negative numbers?  Is it correct to use Mouse.PrimaryDevice in the MouseButtonEventArgs construct?

Comment: By the way, when I click on the Thumb (without raising the event programmatically), the DragDeltaEventArgs are positive numbers and when dragging the Thumb the cursor stays on the thumb...  It's just when I programmatically raise the mouse left button down event that the args are weird...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried an Extension method that uses Reflection to set the IsDragging property of the Thumb rather than raising the MouseLeftButtonDown event.

It works and the cursor stays with the Thumb.  Guess I'll just go with this solution.

```
public void CaptureThumb()
    {
        bottomRight.Focusable = true;
        bottomRight.Focus();
        bottomRight.CaptureMouse();

        //bottomRight.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, Environment.TickCount, MouseButton.Left) { RoutedEvent = Thumb.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent});
        Keyboard.Focus(bottomRight);
        bottomRight.SetPropertyValue("IsDragging", true);
    }

public static class Extensions
{
    private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = null;
        do
        {
            propInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            type = type.BaseType;
        } while (propInfo == null && type != null);
        return propInfo;
    }

    public static void SetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propertyName, object val)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propInfo = GetPropertyInfo(objType, propertyName);

        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("propertyName",
                string.Format("Couldn't find property {0} in type {1}", propertyName, objType.FullName));

        propInfo.SetValue(obj, val, null);
    }
}
```